# Text becomes unreadable after high memory usage

Tags: 14.04, unity

I currently use an old laptop running ubuntu 14.04.2. I am using the default unity desktop. It has an integrated intel graphics card.

After using the laptop for a while, the text becomes unreadable. this usually happens after my RAM usage becomes really high. The text remains unreadable even after the my memory usage lowers. The text only becomes normal after I reboot or log out and log back in but this is time consuming.

I know that this is probably because my laptop is old and not very powerful and I don't really think there is permanent fix for this issue but I would like to know if there is a command that I can run that will make my text readable again without having to reboot my laptop.

I have considered switching over to another desktop environment like Xfce but I really like unity and I haven't had any problems other than this with unity.

It is hard to explain exactly how the text looks but it becomes really glitchy and becomes nearly impossible to read. In some applications like nautilus, the text becomes clear if I hover the mouse over it but it becomes unreadable again if the mouse is moved.

I have tried running some commands to fix this issue but none of them have worked. I ran `unity --replace`but it didnt ake any difference to the text. I really hope that someone from this community can help me fix this problem.

[image: This is how the text looks]

Comment: Some times i also have the same problem in my 14.04.2

Comment: Do you know any method to fix this issue?

Comment: i just log out from my system or do a fresh reboot.. after that its works for me and lastly find which processes make the problem worse and try to not open or run that process again.  For me it was a corrupt bookmark

Answer (score 1):

An old Laptop with integrated Intel graphics has to split conventional memory into OS usage and video ram. There is the possibility that Unity is buggy in low video ram conditions and that the high OS ram usage is a byproduct of the same origin: Too many applications at once.

Try to increase video ram in the BIOS settings. If this does not help, you can still switch to xfce, should not hurt too much.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, although I already switched to xfce a while back

Answer (score 0):

Reseat the memory (ie take it out and put it in again while wearing an anti-static strap). This is common where the memory connectors begin to tarnish with age. While you are at it, it's worth reseating anything pluggable, eg power connectors, at the same time.

Comment: My problem only comes after high memory usage and I don't have really a lot of memory in the laptop anyway ( I only have 2.5 GB, so will this make any difference? also since I am using a laptop I am not entirely sure where the RAM is ill have to search for it but I don't think that would be a problem

Comment: It may be that you have faulty memory. It's worth running the memory test. You should be able to access the grub menu on bootup by pressing the shift key while it's booting, then take the option to test the memory. It's extensive and may take a while to complete 1 loop, but leave it running. It sounds as though you may have a fault in a high memory area which is only accessed when a lot is going on, ie high memory usage.

Comment: OK I will loo into it when i get the chance

Comment: @Rumesh: Did you got any fault on the memtest?

Comment: @Helio I did not really do the test yet.  The problem came less often and I did not have much time to do the test.

Comment: @Rumesh: OK, I have a Latitude E6400 that had this problem with 13.04, but when I installed Ubuntu MATE 14.04 it fixed. So it may be the memory consumption as you said. As is a laptop with Intel Graphics (that uses RAM as graphic memory) it can be a low-ram problem.

Comment: @Helio So I guess my thoughts were correct after all

Comment: @Rumesh Without you running the memory test we are all guessing. I would just d

Comment: @Rumesh Without you running the memory test we are all just guessing. I would just set it going some time when you are not going to use it for an hour or so (it only takes 2 minutes to set it going and it will loop forever until you stop it). If it does report errors, it would then be worth re-seating the memory. Be aware that it there is an intermittent problem the test may run for a while before showing errors.Can't edit the above - sorry

Comment: @Scooby-2 Ok ill do it soon, is it safe to do this overnight? or will it overheat my laptop or something

Comment: @Rumesh My guess is if you leave it to run for just an hour it will do quite a few loops. As for the possibility of overheating, I can state that both my current Lenovo and ancient HP/compaq NX have hardware temperature sensors controlling the fan - just a simple on or off, but there nonetheless - which protects the hardware. What make and model is yours?

Comment: @Scooby-2 Sony vaio VGN-NR120E. it temperature sensors, I can see the temperature of my cpu right now through an applet

Comment: Virtually all laptops have temperature sensors. Many of them rely on the operating system checking the temperatures, and controlling the fan(s) as required. Some (like the Lenovo and my old HP/Compaq) have hardware sensors, ie they are just a thermal switch. They do not need a running operating system to ensure they keep cool. If you go into the BIOS and you hear the fan(s) start after a while you can be pretty sure they are hardware controlled. Some machines without hardware sensors run the fans at full speed until the OS takes over, like my Dell PC. FYI the memory test is not CPU intensive.

Comment: @Scooby-2 ok ill try and do it today itself

Comment: @Scooby-2 I just ran the test twice and they both gave zero errors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24498/discussion-between-scooby-2-and-rumesh).